# Accessing variable from Main window on PopUp window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I have a private String variable called totalCost in my main Window GUI called class PriceCalculator, as well as a getter method called getCost(). I need to access this variable in my secondary window which pops-ups as an event from my main Window.

This is my second Window:

```
public class ExtraWindow extends JDialog {
  public ExtraWindow(JFrame frame) {
    super(frame, "Calculations", true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(300,300);
    centerWindow(this);
  }.......
   ....
```

As you can see, I think the second Window takes the main window as an argument. 
This is where I need the totalCost from the first window:

```
 JLabel lblCost = new JLabel("Cost: ");
```

Since I need to use the information from the specific frame that it's using, I can't make an anonymous or another PriceCalculator and get it from there. I tried doing frame.getCost(), which lead me to casting frame as a PriceCalculator, but my program wouldn't run.

How would I access this variable from the first window, which is an argument for the second?

Sorry, forgot to add, where in the first window, the event happens:

```
public class Event implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        new ExtraWindow(PriceCalculator.this);

    }
```

Comment: Chaneg `public ExtraWindow(JFrame frame)` to `public ExtraWindow(PriceCalculator frame)`, this way you now have direct access ot the `PriceCalculator` and all it's methods...

Comment: Wow, thank you, makes me feel stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You Could...

Change public `ExtraWindow(JFrame frame)` to public `ExtraWindow(PriceCalculator frame)`, this way you now have direct access to the `PriceCalculator` and all it's methods...

### You Could...

Provide an additional parameter that passes the value to the constructor...

```
public ExtraWindow(JFrame frame, double cost) {...
```

### You Could...

Supply a `setCost` method in `ExtraWindow`